# Creating GCP instances without GPUs from a machine image with GPUs

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a Google Cloud machine image that uses GPUs. I want to reuse the same image but run without GPUs.

If I try starting the instance with `gcloud beta compute instances create name machine-type=n2-custom-16-16384` it blows up with an error `[n2-highcpu-16, nvidia-tesla-t4] features are not compatible for creating instance.`.

However, I cannot find a way to specify no accelerator - I tried `--accelerator=""`, `--accelerator=count=0`, `--accelerator=type=nvidia-tesla-t4,count=0` - none of these help, it either tries to use the GPU from the machine image or complains about parameters.

How can I specify no GPU if the machine image specifies one?

[Edit] Even creating the machines using the GUI fails: if I remove the GPU it still tries to attach one. In fact, if I create an n1 type (which supports GPUs), explicitly remove the GPU using GUI, and launch, it will still attach a GPU for me.

Comment: It sounds like youre using a marketplace image. If that's the case surely you're locked in to the GPU parameter. Theres like 400 custom images- surely there's a better one out there for your needs.

Comment: I created my own image from a standard Ubuntu distribution, and then made a machine image out of it. You can add additional GPUs to it, but you can't remove them - which sounds like a bug. For instance, if you remove the GPU via create instance GUI, it will show you pricing without a GPU, and then will create an instance with a GPU in the background without telling you about it - and will bill you.

Comment: Please try this `instances.setMachineResources` API https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/setMachineResources. The correct usage to remove the GPU is to set `"guestAccelerators": []`, and not to set the count to 0. 

Or, there is a new `instances.update` API that also can help you. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/update

Answer (score 0):

I second the suggestion by @Mahboob in the comments.

If that still does not work, there is another hack you can try for this: use [gcloud compute images export](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/images/export) to export the image to a .tar.gz file and then create a new image from that backup without the GPU capability.